# What does Unohana Retsu's Bankai do?

Tags: bleach

What does Unohana Retsu's Bankai do?

It was not so clear in the manga.

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to say what exactly it does... Too little was shown in the manga.

Comment: For now we really can´t say. For all we know it could just be the stab we saw. We´ll probably know in the next couple of chapters.

Comment: She has a bankai?  You saw it?  Where??

Comment: @Makoto Yes, she does. That she has a bankai was revealed during the Soul Society arc itself. What exactly the bankai is wasn't revealed, but that changed recently during the Thousand Years War arc.

Comment: @Deidara-senpai: That wasn't her Bankai in the Soul Society arc. It was seemingly her Shikai.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha It was revealed that she *had* a bankai, but what exactly that is wasn't revealed until recently.

Comment: Leaving that aside, I vote to close this question **for now**, but we keep an eye on it, because it seems this question will become answerable soon.

Comment: Please dont close. I think another chapter of the manga will be released in the next couple of hours or so. I hope we get the answer to this question soon.

Comment: @aikur: When the next chapter will be released, simply flag the question for reopening, and we will reopen it for you. (4 members already agreed to close it, and we don't have many users with closing privilege). If new information comes in, your question will be reopened (right now, it cannot be answered). Don't be discouraged!

Comment: @aikur Close does not mean the question is bad, just that it is currently unsuitable for our SE site. This question is actually *important* for us, since we get some experience on how to deal with questions whose "answerability" changes with time. Rest assured, I wait for Bleach manga each week, and if no one else beats me to it, I will myself flag this for reopening. :)

Comment: @Deidara-senpai Thanks too. I look forward to reopening this. :)

Comment: Doesn't look like he would explain anything more. :(

Comment: Okay. For reasons of SEO, at least two of us in the chatroom believe that currently airing shows where the answer may be revealed in later episodes should be left open. Come to the chatroom to discuss if you disagree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for all the information that is currently available

> she finally enables her Bankai! Blood spills from the skies, as though it was rain, she enables it caller her Minazuki Bankai out! Zaraki notices all the blood that’s dropping! Unohana’s sword is straightened and changes into a sword with never-ending blood oozing from it. She mentions that the play is over!
>   Both of them go crazy and quickly go on their attacks! They keep on clashing, Zaraki can feel that the sword Unohana currently has melts her, it starts to degrade his face from skin to flesh and to bone! He mentions that it’s fun! He notices his hands and cloths degrade away from his bony hands. He asks himself what that is, he mentions that everything seems to be different, at the same time, he sees Unohana with no face except bones!
>   Zaraki mentions that everything is so different, he’s been asleep, he’s  just been dreaming about their contacts over and over again, he calls this exchange to have no name, but thanks to her, she now realizes that this can be called, Fighting! They keep on clashing swords and spilling blood! Unohana mentions that she likes fighting! Zaraki likes it so much that he can’t help it, Zaraki is back to seeing flesh and blood again. [Source](http://dailyanimeart.com/2013/02/13/unohanas-minazuki-bankai-zaraki-kills-unohana-bleach-526/)

It seems like a weird kind of bankai to me very *Illusive*

Comment: I simply did not realize how far out of the loop I was in this series.  Wow.

Comment: @Makoto same i just randomly stumbled upon it haha

Answer (score 1):

Quite simple really . Her bankai ressurects her target as many times as she wants. When Zaraki fought her he mentions having blackouts. They werent just blackouts but  unohana killing & ressurecting him again and again to keep fighting.